# Why does an XML result give NULL on certain selection types?

Tags: sql, null, common-table-expression, for-xml-path

Working with recursive CTEs there are some checks to ensure users can't create an problems loop where a recipe has an ingredient that is the recipe, for example. Attempting to pull user response data via For XML gave an odd result I don't understand.

I can work around the issue with a 3rd CTE but I can't find anything that explains the result I'm getting (I'm probably not phrasing the question well enough for Google).

Set up code that gives the same results -

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT 'A' AS Val
    UNION all
    SELECT 'B' AS Val
    UNION all
    SELECT 'C' AS Val
    ),

    cte2 AS (   
    SELECT 'A' AS Val
    UNION all
    SELECT 'B' AS Val
    UNION all
    SELECT 'D' AS Val
    )
```

Final step either:

```
    cte3 as
        (
        SELECT Val FROM cte1 
        intersect 
        SELECT Val FROM cte2 
        ) 

SELECT  (SELECT Val + ' ' FROM  cte3 FOR XML PATH(''))
```

OR

```
    SELECT Val + ' ' FROM cte1 
    intersect
    SELECT Val + ' ' FROM cte2 
    FOR XML PATH('')
```

OR

```
SELECT (
    SELECT Val + ' ' FROM cte1 
    intersect
    SELECT Val + ' ' FROM cte2 
    FOR XML PATH('')    
    )
```

1st option gives expected "A B".

2nd option also gives "A B" but as an XML output.

3rd option gives NULL, though. Why is that?